# Self powering torch - boost converter calculation

Tags: integrated-circuit, boost, capacitor-charging

I was implementing the TPS61200 Voltage Boost Converter from Texas Instruments in my circuit to boost the voltage output from some Peltier tiles to then power a supercapacitor which would then power an LED.

I consulted a technician on how he worked out that with a 0.5V input I would be able to get 2.375V, using his explanation I could only work out the output to be 1.875V from a 0.5V input.

**I was wondering if I had done my calculations incorrectly or if 2.375V is the true output from a 0.5V input?**

Here is his explanation along with an image of the circuit diagram

"It’s a simple resistive divider! The calculation is below. If you know the feedback pin is 0.5V from the datasheet then the voltage across the 200k resistor is also 0.5V. Using Ohms law gives you the current then Kirchhoff’s law states the current flowing into a node must equal the current flowing out therefore ignoring the current flowing into the FB pin as it is 100 times less than the current flowing through the 200k resistor you have the current flowing through the 750k resistor then you just apply Ohm’s law again to get the voltage! If you take the current flowing into the FB pin as well you should get a more accurate result."

[image]

Comment: Not sure about your question, but your schematic has the FB pin grounded.

Comment: When the output voltage is regulated properly, the typical
value of the voltage at the FB pin is 0.5V. So Vout = 0.5V*(1+R1/R2) = 0.5V*(1+750/200) = 2.375V.  But I suspect you are putting 0.5V at the input of a converter?

Comment: Whats the specs on the LED and what do you expect the super-cap to do?

Comment: You have made too many "green weeny" errors in your schematic. Use current sense feedback instead of voltage sense, that's what LED's prefer http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=SLVA364&fileType=pdf

Comment: as a rule of thumb, it's only easy to boost up to 5X the input.

Comment: Thank you to all those who commented, I am from an undergraduate manufacturing background so I apologies for my lack of electronics knowledge. @G36 I was wondering what is the name of the formula you've used, Vout = Vin*(1 + R1/R2) , is it just a rearrangement of a voltage divider, Vout = Vin*(R2/(R1+R2))? "But I suspect you are putting 0.5V at the input of a converter?" And yes I think I want to connect the peltier tiles to the Vin pin if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Trevor_G the LED in the design is the TruOpto OSB5SA5111A-1V 5mm Low Voltage LED 1.2V Blue 8400MCD 15° Water Clear rated at forward voltage range of 0.8 – 1.6V and DC forward current of 114 mA. This would only produce around 1.34 lumens which is extremely low but I was advised that my Vout would need tp be double the forward voltage of an LED for it to light properly or I wanted to use the Cree (2.0 FDV) XLamp XP-E2 package but this seemingly has a too high forward voltage for my 2.375V output. The supcap is to allow continuous power to the LED when the peltier source isnt supplying charge.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I'm not too sure what you mean by current sense feedback instead of voltage sense feedback, should I change the schematic similar to the one in that link or focus more on the required current rather than voltage of the LED?

Comment: @greensocks you have strange choices for LEDs, show how you intend to use mismatched parts.. You have no clue how to match impedance or LED and Peltier source. Start with what you know works

Answer (score 0):

The TPS61200 is a boost REGULATOR.  That means it will control its duty cycle to maintain the voltage at the feedback pin equal to the internal reference voltage.

The reference is given as 0.5V, so with R2 = 200 kOhms and R1 = 750 kOhms you will have 2.375 volts on the output, assuming you fix your schematic and don't ground the feedback pin.

The explanation given is correct.

Comment: Should I completely remove the ground connection below C3 to remove the feedback pin ground connection? and are there any other changes I need to make to the schematic for it to be viable?

Comment: I assume C3 is your output capacitor, not a feedforward capacitor across the top of your divider.  In that case, C3 needs to go to ground, but do NOT ground the FB pin.  My comments apply to the boost converter.  The supercap and LED portion are another topic probably deserving of a separate question.